# What bird is this seen trekking in Nepal during descent on Manaslu circuit?

Tags: species-identification, species

[image: bird in Nepal]
What bird is this seen trekking in Nepal during descent on Manaslu circuit?

Answer (score 2):

You found an Alpine accentor (*Prunella collaris*). It's a [bird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_accentor) of mountain areas in the Paleartic.

Here is a picture for comparison:

[image]

The only similar bird in the area is the Altai accentor (*Prunella himalayana*), but you can tell it apart because your bird does not have streaked flanks and the more uniform grey head (in your picture it is clearly visible the [supercilium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercilium))